# C#, How to update common fields in models by using interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have common field in all tables

```
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

How can I fill in this field without repeating the code?

I want to do it using the interface.

Comment: If you want to use an interface then use an interface. Define an interface with that property and then implement it in each entity. Does that necessarily help you though? It just means that you can pass an entity of any type to the same method via a reference of that interface type and get or set that property. You've still got to call such a method for every entity. We'd need to know more about what you currently have and what you expect an interface to provide to know what could or would need to be done.

Comment: You don't do things inside an interface. Interfaces are for specifying the members a type has and what type those members are. Implementation details occur in the types that implement the interface. I think that interfaces can have some default implementation these days, although I've never done it, but is that really what you are talking about? I really don't see what you think an interface will do for you. More details definitely required because I think that you are expecting a magic trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create base class and inherit from it in each model class.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Table : BaseModel
{

}
```

If you use an interface, you will still need to implement the property in every class.